# how to create variable as soon as if condition is met in terraform

Tags: if-statement, terraform

I have defined 3 different sizes in variable.tf as below

```
variable size {
  description = "size of the disk"
  type = number
}

variable size2 {
  description = "size of the disk "
  type = number
}

variable size3 {
  description = "size of the disk "
  type = number
}
variable drives {
  description = "drive value (max=3)"
  type = number
}
```

main.tf

```
drives=var.drives
size=var.size 
size2=var.drives==2 ? var.size2:null
size3 =var.drives==3 ? var.size3:null
```

Therefore, I'm attempting to create or take input for size2 and size3 variable only when the values of the cloud drives are 2 and 3, respectively.
But even though I have set the cloud drivers variable to 1, the `terraform plan` command still asks for all three different sizes as input.Since I'm new to Terraform World, could you kindly assist me with this?

Answer (score 1):

> terraform plan command still asks for all three different sizes

Because you did not provide any default values. Thus you have to provide all values for all these parameters. Just define some defaults:

```
variable size2 {
  description = "size of the disk "
  type = number
  default = 0
}

variable size3 {
  description = "size of the disk "
  type = number
  default = 0
}
```

Comment: So if condition is fine in main.tf or it can be modified in a better way

Comment: @AMANJAIN This is a new issue, not related to your question. You should make new SO question about that with relevant code.

Comment: Additionally, I provided the default values, but when I entered 2, it did not request input for size2. var.drives No of drives to provisoned(max=3) Enter a value: 2 var.size size of the disk Enter a value: 100 null_resource.mkdir_kubeconfig_dir: Refreshing state... [id=4420702989914090571]

Comment: @AMANJAIN I already wrote, this is a new issue, thus new question should be made.

Comment: I am asking regarding the default value which you have asked me to add . It is not giving the expected result